# Outlook in Office 2019 (365) not using oauth to connect to gmail or google corporate accounts

Tags: oauth, outlook, gmail

I recently did fresh installs of Windows 10 and installed the latest Office 2019 (Office 365).  All of my google accounts (free gmail accounts and corporate account) have IMAP disabled and app passwords disabled.  I only allow oauth connections to my google accounts.  Outlooks refuses to try oauth and only tries IMAP.  Prior to Win 10 installs I had Win 8.1 with Office 2016 and it connected via oauth to google emails without issue.  I tried on 2 separate Win 10 instances, and then created a fresh Win 10 VM with a fresh Office 2019 install (changed no settings) and behavior across all 3 instances is the same.  If I put in a google address it immediately goes to the IMAP page and asks for a password instead of bringing up an authentication to my google account using 2 factor (2FA).  Additionally I check the box "Advanced options -> Let me set up my account manually" and click on the G (Google) icon and it still doesn't try the oauth authentication - it just goes to the IMAP setup page.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I was able to get in touch with an MS Office support team - if anyone else experiences this issue it has to do with the Office updates channel.  If you are a developer it defaults to a channel that doesn't support oauth.  To fix add the registry key:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\officeupdate]
"updatebranch"="Monthly"

After adding the registry key close all office apps, restart them, go to File -> Office Account -> Update Options - > Update Now and it'll install the missing files.